# How to make an HTML5 video work on iPhone?

Tags: asp.net, iphone, asp.net-mvc-5, html5-video, webm

I have set up an ASP.NET MVC5 video upload-conversion-watching site, and I need it to function on iPhone. The two formats I support are webm and flv;

- **I am NOT implementing .mp4 format due to the licensing requirements**.

Is there an iPhone app, JavaScript library, or an extension that will allow the video to be played programmatically by my site, or an external iPhone application that can do it. The potential user base varies wildly in terms of technical experience, so any method will need to be relatively simple to follow. It would obviously be best if there were a way I could do it automatically, but I will take anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a way to do this and found a JavaScript library that apparently isn't shown on Google when searching for this question.

https://github.com/brion/ogv.js

Despite the name, it could also do WebM and not just OGV.

Hope this helps for anyone who stumbles upon this question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).